# Android : Dimension types not allowed & define correct unit

Tags: android, types

when generating my apk, I get a lot of errors in my xml files, of course I'm not gonna post all of them. 
I have been trying to fix integer types error by adding 'dp' to the values, however, it's not always the right thing to add, which I can understand, but I do not know what's the correct fix to these.

For instance, I get :

```
Error: Dimension types not allowed (at 'layout_gravity' with value '11dp').
```

but if I do not put the "dp" I get

```
Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_gravity' with value '11').
```

same problem with :shape, ShowAsAction, type, TileMode, ScaleType, LayoutWeight, StretchMode, TextStyle....

I also get an error with "color" :

```
Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'color' with value '0x106000c').
```

same problem  : background, id, drawable(same kind of string)

However, it seems kind of odd that the fix would be to define the type of each elements, so if it comes from somewhere else, I would like to know the solution,
and if I have to define each elements' type, sure, but I need to know the matching type then

thanks/

Comment: layout_gravity expects a word, such as `bottom`, `end`, `start`, `center`, `top` ..... At least for a LinearLayout. This [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html), list all of the values. It was found by searching for **android layout_gravity xml**. You could find the values for other elements do doing a similar search.

Comment: With colours you would used a defined color e.g. `android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"` where **colors.xml** would/could contain `<color name="colorBlack">#000000</color>`

Comment: Just to clarify, searching was a google search not a search through files in your code/project.

Comment: is it mandatory to declare a unit for pretty much all these ? I am updating an app from 2014, and a lot of values that are numbers seemed to correspond to something. I have very little knowledge to Android developpment, if this evolved and it is mandatory okay, but I'd like to be sure

Comment: If you code an item/element then a value is mandatory ("" is valid for strings). However, not all elements are mandatory and whether or not they are mandatory can be situational. e.g. I don't believe that coding `android:layout_gravity=""` is mandatory. If an optional element is omitted then the default characteristic(s) will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity should be provided as Predefined values such as  `android:gravity="center_vertical"` in xml

for colors also you should use color codes or predefined colors

Answer (score 0):

Gravity can be `CENTER_HORIZONTAL`, `CENTER_VERTICAL` or `CENTER`, it can't have value in dp.

Hex color is defined like `#fff` not `0xFFF`